# The Center is located at five sites in Honolulu

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> The Center **is** located at five sites in Honolulu.

I found this on the Internet. I am confused why this uses singular form "the center is" regardless of "five sites". Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Yes. The subject is "The Center" (singular).

Comment: A single institution, like "The Center" here, can be spread across multiple locations. It's still one "center".

Answer (score 2):

**The Center is located at five sites in Honolulu**

- The subject is *The Center* (singular) and the *at five site* is a prepositional phrase indicates that the *The Center* has five branches (building sites) situated in five particular areas in Honolulu; these branches belong to the same *Center* ( which is the subject).
- Example; "**Researchers founded LIGO in 1992. It is located in two sites; one at Hanford, Washington and the other is at Livingston, Louisiana**"
  So the sentence is correct.